# A way to enable or disable media query in browsers that also works in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

If you have multiple media queries on a page you can set the conditionText of the rule to enable or disable a rule:

```
// enables a rule
document.styleSheets[2].rules[0].conditionText= "(min-width: 0px)";

// disables a rule
document.styleSheets[2].rules[0].conditionText= "(min-width: 99999px)";
```

This works on all major browsers except, as I just found out, for Safari.

Is there another way to enable or disable a media query rule?

Note: Using the code above enables and disables the media query by saying, "If the browser is not less than 0px wide then enable this query" and 
"Unless the browser is 99999px wide do not enable these styles". I couldn't find a enable or disable property.

Comment: This seems like a fragile way to do it, but how about modifying the rule to include a deprecated and unlikely device-type: `tty and (min-width: 99999px)`? Or you could use a non-existant device-type, leading to: `thisDeviceTypeDoesNotExist and (min-width: 99999px)`, although, honestly, I think changing the device-type would negate the need for the use of the `min-width` condition.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I've been looking for alternatives.

Comment: Added your condition to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. Need to do some more testing:

```
var inclusionQuery = "(min-width: 0px)";
var exclusionQuery = "noDeviceIsEverNamedThis and (min-width: 99999px)";

function enableMediaQuery(rule) {

    try {
        rule.media.mediaText = inclusionQuery;
    }
    catch(error) {
        rule.conditionText = inclusionQuery;
    }
}

function disableMediaQuery(rule) {

    try {
        rule.media.mediaText = exclusionQuery;
    }
    catch(error) {
        rule.conditionText = exclusionQuery;
    }
}
```

Added non existing device exclusion from @DavidThomas.

In earlier tests the mediaText or a related property was read only but it seems to be on Safari. Will update the answer.

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised there's no API to activate/deactivate specific (ideally named) media queries.

Comment: That's a great feature request. Could be applied to any rule.

Comment: I'm not sure I have a good [strawman proposal](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) for why such an API should exist, or what utility it should have (or be extended to cover); but if you want to follow through and make a strawman/level 0 proposal for a future version of EcmaScript: https://esdiscuss.org/